# String Functions and select statements in Reports

Tags: reports-api

I Have two questions in Reports

1. How to address String functions in Salesforce Reports?
2. Can we get any value from Select statement in a Formula column?

Comment: 1- What do you mean exactly?   2- No you can not.

Answer (score 0):

Report Formulas are basically an aggregation formulas with some logic applied, but most of the functions can not be used. It can only return a number or currency type.